# Why does ffmpeg -filter_complex hstack distort images?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have prepared two videos -

`obamap.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'obamap.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Movie Test
    artist          : Matplotlib
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    comment         : Movie support!
  Duration: 00:00:02.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 173 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 500x500, 106 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

`obamapl.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'obamapl.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 143 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 500x500 [SAR 4:3 DAR 4:3], 137 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Next they are stacked horizontally with -

```
ffmpeg -i obamap.mp4 -i obamapl.mp4 -filter_complex hstack=inputs=2 combined_1.mp4


ffprobe combined_1.mp4                                                                     
ffprobe version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
...
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'combined_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Movie Test
    artist          : Matplotlib
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    comment         : Movie support!
  Duration: 00:00:02.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 294 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1000x500, 228 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

In the resulting file `combined_1.mp4`, the right side `obamapl.mp4` looks squashed horizontally

When the stacking order is reversed with -

```
!ffmpeg -i obamapl.mp4 -i obamap.mp4 -filter_complex hstack=inputs=2 combined_2.mp4

ffprobe combined_2.mp4
ffprobe version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
...

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'combined_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 290 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1000x500 [SAR 4:3 DAR 8:3], 222 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

In the resulting file `combined_2.mp4`, the right side `obamap.mp4` looks stetched horizontally.

How can I avoid this squashing and stretching?

Answer (score 1):

The effective display size of the video is the video's stored resolution modulated by the sample/pixel aspect ratio.

`obamapl.mp4` has `SAR 4:3` so a compliant player will convert it to `500*4/3x500` = `667x500` which produces a DAR of 4:3.

You should scale it to square pixels before stacking.

`ffmpeg -i obamap.mp4 -i obamapl.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=2*trunc(iw*sar/2):ih[r];[0][r]hstack=inputs=2" combined_1.mp4`

Comment: I tried your solution but received error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token (`. What do the two `[r]` symbols mean?

Comment: They are linklabels. See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1